# How can I wipe an encrypted volume when the password is forgotten?

Tags: command-line, disk-utility, encryption, macos, disk-volume

I have encrypted disk volume that is in the way and the passphrase is gone.

How can I erase the contents and reuse the disk space?

Answer (score 1):

To delete encrypted volume disk (not your main boot disk)

1. Open `Terminal.app`
2. Unmount disk using

   `diskutil unmountDisk force /Volumes/disk2` (substitute /Volumes/disk2 with your disk)
3. Find disk UUID

   `diskutil coreStorage list`
4. Delete disk/volume

   `diskutil coreStorage delete [UUID]` (substitute [UUID] with your disk's UUID obtained from the previous command)